# EE4 - Channel Images exception caught

Tags: channel-images

Today I updated my website to ExpressionEngine 4 without much trouble. However, there's one thing I cannot get fixed.

Apparently the Channel Images plugin is giving errors, but I really don't know what to do or how to fix this.

The error message:

```
Exception Caught
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'field_group' in 'field list':
SELECT `field_group` FROM (`exp_channels`) WHERE `channel_id` = '2'

ee/legacy/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_connection.php:116
Stack Trace: Please include when reporting this error
```

I already tried to manually add the field_group column, but if I do another exception pops up.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: For the moment Channel Image is not yet EE4 compatible. But the DevDemon Team is working on it.

Answer (score 0):

As Channel Image is not yet compatible for EE4, for the moment you have to come back to EE3, and restore the backup EE3 files and database, thus using EE3 no more error problems.

Now you have to wait the Channel Images to be compatible with EE4 to use them without problems.